# Kali Linux vpn installing issues

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, kali-linux

I have looked at questions about how to install a VPN on kali but I still can't get it to work for me. I used the following commands to begin getting the VPN. I am aware that there are more commands but I can't even get the first one to work. Here are the commands and their output:

```
# apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
# apt-get install network-manager-pptp 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package network-manager-pptp is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package 'network-manager-pptp' has no installation candidate
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! If it is a newbie question then I apologize as I am new to Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open you terminal and type those text in below

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

After that you clear the text file paste

```
#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 _Kali_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20141002-11:29]/ kali contrib main non-free
#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 _Kali_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20141002-11:29]/ kali contrib main non-free

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib

## Security updates
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

After that you save the file and exit.

Then type in terminal

> apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

If it fail then try two or three times. After that you can install network packages.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to install VPN offline on Kali2 , there are necessary .deb files downloaded and shared publicly:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzVw5nmVUkkyWUxoMXpYWUgwS1E/view?usp=sharing

Download .tar.gz file and then extract it:

```
tar -xvzf vpn.tar.gz
Go to the directory "vpn/3" and install all packages in it:
dpkg --install *.deb
```

Run above command at least 2 times since some have dependency to others and at the first place, dependencies must be installed.

Comment: Surely, there is another source for these files, other than some Google Drive file?